# e.preventDefault(); prevents bubbling, BUT how can we prevent capture phase from going down further to children

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

`e.preventDefault();` prevents bubbling, BUT how can we prevent capture phase from going down further to children.

Basically, I have parent and children elements all having click events, but I want to trigger click ONLY of parent and not of the children when user clicks the child.

In following example when user clicks any `a` tag it should not redirect user to the href page instead should fire click event of the `parentdiv` element

```
<div id='parentdiv'>
    <a href="a.html"></a>
    <a href="b.html"></a>
    <a href="c.html"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you have click events on the children if you don't want them to be clicked?

Comment: Old click events attached we need to live with it for now.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand it, `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default behaviour (submitting when clicking a submit button, following the url when clicking on a link). `e.stopPropagation()` stops the event from bubbling to other listeners, so maybe that's the one you want.

[[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)]

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` not just stops bubbling, it also stops capturing (if used with addEventListener's second argument as `true`)

Comment: This will only prevent the parent element's click handler from firing when a child element is clicked, not the other way around.

Comment: @DerekMT12: That's true. But if you're using a capturing listener, that'll be called first, and so if `e.stopPropagation()` is used in that first capturing listener, it'll kill the rest of the listeners for that event.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the parent to receive the touch event you can add

`pointer-events: none`

in the css for the children elements.